# Pgrouting functions and geoms type not found. Install failed?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0, osm2pgrouting

I have installed a `postgresql 9.1` and `postgis 2.0` from source.

I couldn't launch this :

```
# Add pgRouting launchpad repository ("stable" or "unstable")
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:georepublic/pgrouting[-unstable]
sudo apt-get update

# Install pgRouting packages
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-pgrouting
```

So I compiled and installed `pgrouting 2.0` (after some hours searching for dependencies).
I created the extension on my database in `postgresql`.

I included the function from the `sql` files `pgrouting.sql` but the functions I need are in `pgrouting_legacy.sql` and `pgrouting_dd_legacy.sql`

When I try to load them, the error I get is : `psql:/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/pgrouting-2.0/pgrouting_legacy.sql:299: ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist`

Postgresql and Postgis are working fine...

What did I wrong ? Maybe I forgot something or the install failed ?

I followed this documentation : http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html

http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=pgrouting_osm2po_1

Answer (score 1):

(1) About compiling problems

You wrote that you compiled PostgreSQL and PostGIS from source. Probably required libraries or header files are not found.

It seems that you are using Ubuntu, so I don't really understand why you don't use the default PostgreSQL and PostGIS packages. For PostGIS 2.0 Launchpad PPA's exist as well.

(2) About using the correct documentation

It seems you read pgRouting 1.x documentation, but you try to install version 2.0. The correct documentation you can find here: http://docs.pgrouting.org/

(3) Better use `CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;`

With pgRouting 2.0 (and PostgreSQL 9.1) you can install pgRouting with `CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;` and you don't need to install SQL files manually anymore.

In short, for Ubuntu just run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-pgrouting postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0
```

The connect to the database and run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realized that I can not run the legacy functions in pgrouting 2.0. 
For the install of PostgreSql and PostGis, I had to compile them because the default install didn't worked. I had to set some options when I launched ./configure ... 
So, It worked when I installed it by the repository of Ubuntu. Thank you agaain.

Comment: Mirza: if your problem is solved, you should upvote the answer (arrow above the number on the left size) and mark it as "the answer".